# How do I draw my sprite using strictly public Character and a function

Tags: c#, function, class, sprite, public

So I have to make Boulder Dash from C64 with C# as a project for school but I'm stuck at the place where I have to draw Rockford(the character). My english is pretty poor for what I want to explain but when you'll see the code, it'll be easier to understand. Everything that's about the character is in the class "Character" and then I have to use public Character to create the sprite, to draw it, I have a function

I don't know how to transfer the sprite from public Character to the function, I tried many things, recreating the character in the function, even tried calling "public Character" in my Draw function

```
public Character(string Image, int x, int y, Direction dir)
{
   Image = "images/heros24.bmp";
   x = 4;
   y = 3;
   dir = Direction.Left;
   Texture tRockford = new Texture(Image);
   Sprite sRockford = new Sprite(tRockford);
}


public void Afficher(RenderWindow fenetre, float PixelByCase)
{
 string Image = "images/heros24.bmp";
 int x = 4;
 int y = 3;
 Direction dir = Direction.Left;
 Character p = new Character(Image, x, y, dir);
 Vector2f position = new Vector2f(X * PixelsParCell, Y * PixelsParCell);
 p.Position = position;
 fenetre.Draw(p);
}
```

Comment: Is Character a class or a function? Presumably it’s the former? What parameter type does RenderWindow Draw take? Please show a minimal code example that shows the problem you’re having. I loved playing that game on the c64 btw!

Comment: @auburg there's no code? I thought I've put my code but basically the problem is telling me there's no defintion for .Position in Program.Character but I can't find a solution

Comment: _no defintion for .Position in Program.Character_ Indeed, there isn't. But, seriously, this question lacks all important info we would need to help/advise. You don't event tell us for which platform you develop.